# collate 500 excel sheets into database

Tags: excel

i have 500 excel sheets which are used for data collection from various organisations
i need to collate all the data into a variety of summary excel sheets

at the moment this is all done manually, cut and paste and then create big forumlas to calculate across several sheets to tally it up

i am looking to automate this somehow, I would like to run a set of tests on the excel files to make sure the data is correct, and them import it all into a database, and then spit summary sheets back out in excel format.

is there something out there that does this sort of thing already, based on a set of rules ?

Comment: What sort of database (and version) are you looking at using?  SQL Server has the capabilities of using SSIS packages to import data from Excel spreadsheets into a database table.

Comment: i am open minded about the solution, i have used dotnet and sqlserver before what is SSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a number of excel projects where I needed to import data from an uploaded spreadsheet.  I used this library and built what i needed out of it:

http://excelpackage.codeplex.com

Example to read data:

http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Reading%20data%20from%20an%20Excel%20spreadsheet

It's a .net solution though...

Comment: a lot of these sheets are still in excel95 format, it will work ok for writing data out, so that is half the problem solved